# Wordpress Parameter background change

Tags: wordpress

Afternoon all

I never use wordpress. I am looking for a simplest solution for the following:

I have a wordpress site.

for a param e.g   website.com/cars....
I want to change the background of the site to a car related background

for a param e.g   website.com/boats....
I want to change the background of the site to a boat related background

Ideally would like to get this to 100s of backgrounds.

I have no idea in the wordpress world if there is a plugin or what the best practice is for something like this.

Before I start I am all open to ideas

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go something like this:

For eg: page url :  website.com/cars
slug     :  cars

Here I would suggest you to keep the name of image as : cars.png/jpg
and in setting up the image :

```
$postId = get_the_ID();
        $slug = basename(get_permalink($postId));
        echo $slug;
```

once you get the $slug value use it as a "path+$slug.png/jpg"

Comment: Apologies, very primitive of me, but where in wordpress do I place this?

Comment: You have to edit the template file, where you need to call the image.